# How do I open the file picked with FileChooser?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use FileChooser and I am stumped by how I can open the chosen file. Since the file can be of any type - pdf, docx etc, how do show the file inside codenameone or give an option for user to chose preferred application to open it. Being able to determine what of type of file it is and then based on that offering options to open it.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch file chooser you specify the type of file you want. If you want any file type at all it's the assumption that you would know how to deal with that file type. E.g. any file type is usually used to upload files to a server.

If you want to view a file you can usually use the `execute` method (in `Display`/`CN`) to display a URL which in this case would be a file URL.